# In SSRS : How to group Records based on some column

Tags: reporting-services

I want to create a report

[image]

so I have data that has column called OfficerId and Officername,

based on these two column(`OfficerId,OfficerName)` I want to group the records so that in a textbox these value and the associated record with these column below in a table form.
How to do it?

Comment: What you have tried so for?

Comment: I tried Creating a table with OfficerName and OfficerD,Inserted a row inside Group - Below,in that inserted a subreport.But it is in  table format.Is that possible I can get the distinct  Officername and OfficerID in a textbox and below its details in tabular form?

Comment: I've been observed that you are just asking question, but not giving update to the person who is answering on your question. If answer helped you then mark as it answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry but can you just tell me how to mark the answer?so that in future i can do the correct thing

Comment: Click the green outlined check mark to the left of the answer that solved your problem. This marks the answer as "accepted", and by extension the question as "has an accepted answer".